# Problema en peticion FETCH()

Tags: javascript, fetch

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que recoge unos archivos externos alojados en el mismo servidor mediante la API Fetch, pero no me funciona y juraría que está bien implementado,no consigo ver el error.
Los archivos externos están en la carpeta archivosExternos alojada en la misma raiz que los archivos html, con lo que la ruta es correcta.El enlace al archivo js tb es correcto, de hecho la función ocultarTexto() funciona

Pero no me imprime nada en el contenedor de destino

Este es el código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>UF4 Entorno Cliente</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css" />
    <noscript>
        Para utilizar las funcionalidades completas de este sitio es necesario tener JavaScript habilitado. Aquí están
        las <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/es/"> instrucciones para habilitar JavaScript en tu navegador
            web</a>.
    </noscript>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cabecera">
        <h1>ACTIVIDAD UF4 ENTORNO CLIENTE</h1>
        <h2>Modificar información de un archivo HTML por el contenido de un archivo *.txt externo mediante la API FETCH
        </h2>
        <h3 class="blue">La API Fetch proporciona una interfaz JavaScript para acceder y manipular partes del canal
            HTTP, tales como peticiones y respuestas. Proporciona una forma fácil y lógica de obtener recursos de forma
            asíncrona por la red.<br> Este método si que permite crear varias peticiones y mantenerlas todas a la
            escucha para imprimir diferentes archivos externos alojados en el servidor
        </h3>
          </div>
        <div id="navegacion">
            <p> <a href="index.html"><input type="button" value="VOLVER AL INDICE" /></a>
                <a href="conAjax.html"><input type="button" value="VER ACTIVIDAD CON AJAX" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
  

    <div id="botones">
        <p style="text-align:center"><a href="archivoExterno/texto1.txt" target="_blank"><input type="button"
                    value="TEXTO EXTERNO 1" /></a>
            <a href="archivoExterno/texto2.txt" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="TEXTO EXTERNO 2" /></a>
            <a href="archivoExterno/texto3.txt" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="TEXTO EXTERNO 3" /></a>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align:center">
            <input id="1" type="button" value="MOSTRAR TEXTO 1"  />
            <input id="2" type="button" value="MOSTRAR TEXTO 2" />
            <input id="3" type="button" value="MOSTRAR TEXTO 3" />

        </p>
        <p style="text-align:center">
            <input id="ocultarTexto" type="button" value="OCULTAR TEXTO"  />
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 style="text-align:center">El texto externo se insertará en el recuadro inferior<br>El scroll en el texto se
        realiza con el ratón, se ha ocultado la barra de scroll con CSS</h3>
    <div id="containerTextos">

        <div id="salidaTexto">
            <p style="text-align:center">Este texto se eliminarà y será sustituido por el nuevo texto desde el archivo
                externo o
                al clicar en el botón <strong>ocultar texto</strong></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>©Copyleft 2022  Trabajo perteneciente a la UF4 de Diseño Web en
            Entorno Cliente. 2º DAW</p>

        </p>

    </footer>

    <!-- Enlace al archivo JS-->
    <script src="js/conFetch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Y este el js enlazado

```javascript
//Asignamos a una constante el elemento del DOM que queremos manipular
const BOTON1 = document.getElementById("1");
const BOTON2 = document.getElementById("2");
const BOTON3 = document.getElementById("3");
const OCULTARTEXTO= document.getElementById("ocultarTexto");
const CAJATEXTOS = document.getElementById("salidaTexto");

/* Se añade un evento a cada botón para que al pulsarlos se ejecute la función*/
BOTON1.addEventListener("click", seleccionarTextoExterno);
BOTON2.addEventListener("click", seleccionarTextoExterno);
BOTON3.addEventListener("click", seleccionarTextoExterno);
OCULTARTEXTO.addEventListener("click", ocultarTexto);


/* Función que selecciona el texto segun pulsemos un boton u otro */
function seleccionarTextoExterno(e) {

    //Se comprueba que boton se ha pulsado
    if (e.target.value == 1) { //Si se ha pulsado el boton 1
        fetch("archivoExterno/texto1.txt") //Se hace una petición fetch al archivo externo
            .then((res) => { //Se recoge la respuesta
                return res.text(); //Se devuelve el contenido del archivo
            })
            .then((contenido) => { //Se recoge el contenido del archivo
                CAJATEXTOS.innerHTML = contenido; //Se muestra el contenido en el elemento del DOM
            });
    }
    else
        if (e.target.value == 2) {
        fetch("archivoExterno/texto2.txt")
            .then((res) => {
                return res.text();
            })
            .then((contenido) => {
                CAJATEXTOS.innerHTML = contenido;
            });
        }
        else
            if (e.target.value == 3) {
        fetch("archivoExterno/texto3.txt")
            .then((res) => {
                return res.text();
            })
            .then((contenido) => {
                CAJATEXTOS.innerHTML = contenido;
            });
    }
}

/* Función que oculta el texto */
function ocultarTexto() {
    CAJATEXTOS.innerHTML = "";
}
```

¿Alguna idea? He mirado decenas de tutoriales de Fetch() y no veo el error por ninguna parte

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Dos consejos. Primero: cuando muestres el contenido de texto de un archivo, hazlo haciendo uso de [`Element.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), y no `.innerHTML`, para que los caracteres que puedan ser confundidos por entidades HTML no sean interpretados. Esto mitiga la mayoría de ataques XSS que puedan producirse si el archivo que debes obtener de manera remota puede ser manipulado por el usuario. Además, si usas `<pre>` en vez de `<div>`, mantendrás mejor el formato del contenido (sobre todo la separación de líneas).

Comment: Segundo consejo: Si vas a realizar varios `if` mutuamente excluyentes, el código queda más claro y legible haciendo uso de estructuras `switch / case` que mediante `if / else if` anidados. Además, podrías haber metido las URLs de los archivos en una lista o matriz cuyos índices sean el valor de `e.target.value` (recuerda que es una cadena de caracteres, no un valor numérico) para no tener que repetir tanto código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer la condicional `if` está mal declarada. No hay ningún `value` que sea 1 sino que: `MOSTRAR TEXTO 1`.

Puedes probar con:

```
if (e.target.value == "MOSTRAR TEXTO 1")
```

Ó usando su ID:

```
if (e.target.id == 1)
```

Ó directamente

```
if (e.target == BOTON1)
```

Comment: Tod la razón, Narciso. Muchísimas gracias, era eso, no sé por qué tuve el click de usar la identidad para los botones y recuperar el value en lugar de la identidad. Gracias de nuevo